# IPython closes when I try to start it

Tags: python, ipython

I was trying to install the latest version of IPython, but kept giving an exception error when cleaning up. I tried various ways to do this. Now I download it the 1.2.1-2 version, I start it and the window closes immediatly. I've removed it since. Now here's the error I get:

```
$ pip3 install traitlets

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

$ sudo ipython

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 22, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
ImportError: No module named 'traitlets'
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and have the 3.4 and 3.5 Python versions installed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Please [edit] the question and add the full output (error message), so we may be able to help you.

Comment: As you can see, `traitlets` is installed for Python 3.4 but `iPython` is installed for Python 3.5.

Comment: @edwinksl So could OP run `sudo pip3.5 install traitlets` to fix the issue?

Comment: If you run IPython without `sudo`, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Ipython is with [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).